# 'not declared in this scope' when using strlen()

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile this piece of code but for whatever reason it won't work. Can someone help me? I want to know how to use strlen() properly:

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
    char buffer[80];

    cout << "Enter a string:";
    cin >> buffer;
    cout << strlen(buffer);

    return 0;

 }
```

I've tried using cin.getline(buffer, 80); but I get the same compile error issue.

My compiler says the error is this

> error: strlen was not declared in this scope

Comment: my compiler says this:error: âstrlenâ was not declared in this scope

Comment: what's wrong with the code??

Comment: check out this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)

Comment: I found that if I use `gcc` instead of `g++` it works.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You forgot to include `<cstring>` or `<string.h>`.

`cstring` will give you `strlen` in the `std` namespace, while `string.h` will keep it in the global namespace.

Answer (score 11):

You need to include `cstring` header for `strlen`:

```
 #include <cstring>
```

you could alternatively include `string.h` and that would put `strlen` in the global namespace as opposed to `std` namespace. I think it is better practice to use `cstring` and to drop using [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can include  `<cstring>`, then you won't get any errors.

code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
    char buffer[80];

    cout << "Enter a string:";
    cin >> buffer;
    cout << strlen(buffer);

    return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use string.h header file in C++ but it is generally not recommended. In C++, the string class is part of the standard library and provides more functionality for manipulating strings than the functions declared in string.h.

The string class provides features like dynamic memory allocation, overloaded operators, iterators, and more, making it easier to work with strings in C++. Using string.h in C++ may limit the benefits of these features and make the code harder to read and maintain.

To use the string class in C++, you can include the  header file. This header file declares the std::string class and associated functions and provides a more modern and efficient way of working with strings in C++.